# Python Sort list field 1 ascending and shuffle field 2

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have list with 2 fields where I can sort ascending and descending.

```
most_frequent_sorted=sorted(most_frequent, key = operator.itemgetter(1,0), reverse=False)
```

But actually I want that  Field 0 should shuffle every time I run the code and only field 1 should be sorted.

I don't understand how to apply list.Shuffle in this multi-Field list. Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just adding this code above the code did the trick.

```
random.shuffle(most_frequent)
```